# Getting an error with shoco.js (Uncaught TypeError: $.stackSave is not a function)

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the shoco (de)compression software. In specific I am using JS version. I am getting this error:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: $.stackSave is not a function
    at Object.v.Xa (shoco.js:2969)
    at f (shoco.js:403)
    at shoco.js:413
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ma (shoco.js:412)
    at shoco.js:424
    at Object.compress (shoco.js:19)
    at setMessage (post.html:87)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (post.html:28)`
```

FYI: the `post.html` is just where I call `shoco.compress`

Here is that code: `shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value)`

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was using two different types of scripts for my JS, and one of them was set wrongly.